# When can protection from creatures be played

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The other day I was in a situation where my opponent had 3 creatures on the board (4/4, 3/3, 1/1) and I had one creature on the board (6/6). My opponent attacked with all three creatures and I chose to block the 4/4 with my 6/6. Then my opponent played [Divine Verdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Divine%20Verdict) on my 6/6 then also tried to play  [Crypsis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypsis) on the 4/4 that I blocked.

Am I correct in assuming that it was too late for the protection from creature card to be played because the combat damage had already been done?

Comment: I would nominate this to be closed as it is very unclear what is being asked.

Comment: I fixed some formatting and also added cards that do what you are describing, if you feel they aren't right feel free to change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can play a card that gives their creature protection, but it is probably pointless if they are playing a card that destroys the blocking creature anyway.

In the combat phase there are 5 steps

1. Begining of Combat
2. Declare Attackers
3. Declare Blockers
4. Combat Damage
5. End of Combat

During each of these steps each player gains priority and can cast spells/activate abilities if they want to. In your example the card giving protection must be cast at the latest in the Declare Blockers step, because the first thing that happens in the Combat Damage step is combat damage being assigned, which would deal lethal damage to the 4/4 and send it to the graveyard. However casting the card giving protection is pointless since with the 6/6 being destroyed there is nothing that will deal damage to it. Even though Protection prevents blocking once a creature is blocked removing the blocker or giving the attack protection does not stop the attacker from being blocked.

Comment: If opponent was thinking he could cast that to make his 4/4 unblocked he would be wrong. He would need to give it trample to get that 4 damage in.

Comment: @diego so the destroy blocking creature would actually prevent the damage to the creature being blocked?

Comment: @thatdude1087 It would not prevent the damage, it would cause the damage to never occur in the first place since the creature is dead.

Comment: ok so it resolves before any combat damage

Comment: @thatdude1087 Yes, the stack must be empty and all players must pass priority before moving to the next step or phase